# When upgrading to Polymer 2.0, what should I use to replace queryEffectiveChildren() in a Polymer.Element

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a Polymer 1 element which uses queryEffectiveChildren() to check whether the slot's DOM is populated:

`if(this.queryEffectiveChildren('[slot="description"]').childElementCount > 0) {`

The queryEffectiveChildren function is not available in Polymer 2.0's Polymer.Element, so what should I use to perform the above check?

Comment: did not really use Polymer 1, but isn't this the kind of thing that you might be able to achieve using just the plain JS `querySelector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Polymer.LegacyElementMixin`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/mixins/Polymer.LegacyElementMixin) to use [`queryEffectiveChildren`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/mixins/Polymer.LegacyElementMixin#method-queryEffectiveChildren) (or other legacy APIs):

```
customElements.define('x-foo', class extends Polymer.LegacyElementMixin(Polymer.Element) {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    let x = this.queryEffectiveChildren('[slot="description"]');
    // ...
  }
});
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OzdNRJ?editors=1011)

Or the equivalent, as described in the [2.0 upgrade guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#polymer-dom-apis):

```
customElements.define('x-foo', class extends Polymer.LegacyElementMixin(Polymer.Element) {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    let x = Polymer.FlattenedNodesObserver
              .getFlattenedNodes(this)
              .filter(n => n.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
              .filter(n => n.parentNode.querySelector('[slot="description"]') === n);
              // OR: .filter(n => n.getAttribute('slot') === 'description');
  }
});
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zpeqdW?editors=1011)

Comment: Accepted your answer because it's right. I just think that it's a shame there's nothing in 2.0 to make this a bit simpler.